# Type family forcing parameter to have the kind *

Tags: haskell, type-families, type-kinds

This simple code doesn't compile

```
import Data.Kind
type family F (k :: Type) :: (t :: k) -> Type
```

The error message is

```
• Expected a type, but ‘t’ has kind ‘k’
• In the kind ‘(t :: k) -> Type’
```

I get in some sense that this actually defines a "family of type families" but I don't really understand why this limitation would exist.

```
type family F (k :: Type) (t :: k) :: Type
```

does work but it doesn't have the same semantics and can't be used the same.

Comment: Aren't things on the right side of the `::` for a type family kinds? So the first one (would) say "kind t has sort k" while the second one says "type t has kind k"?

Comment: With TypeInType it's all the same.

Comment: Perhaps `type family F (k :: Type) :: k -> Type` is closer to what you want?

Comment: @chi Wow, of course. I have no idea why I over complicated that so much.

Comment: Type families are not real 'functions'. The 2nd type family does not have type `(k :: Type) -> (t :: k) -> Type`. In fact, it has no type which can be currently expressed in Haskell. The first type family is invalid because `(->) :: Type -> Type -> Type` but you've explicitly declared `t :: k` and `k` (a fresh type variable) doesn't unify with `Type`. `(t :: Type) -> Type` would be completely valid (and is equivalent to the type in the accepted answer).

Comment: @user2407038 I'm pretty sure (->) is polykinded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to name `t` in the resulting type. You can can simply use

```
type family F (k :: Type) :: k -> Type
```